# Looking for 10GHz range clock generator

Tags: clock, pll

A bit of background: I'm doing some research with Doppler cooling and I need to design a new electronics package to tune a set of lasers to stimulate various two photon transitions.

At the moment, the laser locking package makes use of the ADF4350, (it's the eval kit). However, for this new application I need to use something in the 10GHz range. The closest thing I could find was this series:

https://www.hittite.com/products/view.html/view/HMC778LP6CE

A perusal of popular suppliers: TI, AD again, SiLabs, Lattice Semi, etc, has yielded little outside of 3GHz (makes sense I guess, for 6Gbps video?). Also, while I wouldnt mind designing the board, I would prefer a dev kit as it would save time.

Just wondering if anyone has any suggestions.

Thanks.

EDIT: someone made a good point, I'm looking for an oscillator and not a clock. I need it to be fairly close to a delta function around the fundamental. I've found some good ones at RFMD.

Comment: I think they use tunnel diodes in Doppler radars as the oscillator and output device.

Comment: Hittite does have eval boards for most of their parts. You can see a link for "Eval PCB schematic" on the page you linked. Whether they'll give you a board or sell you one probably depends what kind of institutional or corporate connections you can invoke.

Comment: Ah beauty! Did not see! Derp. TYVM. I'd still like to see if someone comes up with any alternatives, but thank you, this is likely what I will end up pursuing.

Comment: FYI, RFMD is another vendor to look at.

Comment: RE: Tunnel Diode   AFAIK you still have to seed the diode circuit with a fast enough pulse? Not sure that is a viable option.

Comment: Hardly anyone calls an oscillator for 10 GHz a clock. Search "10GHz Oscillator" and you will find them all over the place, including eBay. And that's a sine wave. To get even the first approximation to a 10 GHz square wave you need 30 GHz.

Comment: Sure, good point, I've clarified.

Comment: What is your question? You found the Hittite part. What about it is not adequate for your application?

Answer (score 1):

yeah I would use this and a compatible buffer to make sure correct 10GHz pulses are being delivered. I suggest the item below

https://www.hittite.com/products/view.html/view/HMC720LP3E